# Files uploaded into subfolders based on their filenames

Tags: php, upload

I'm a n00b and I need some help figuring out this issue, I would be grateful for all the help that I can get.

So…the idea is when a user uploads for example "Abiotic Stress in Plants.pdf", it is uploaded into a folder called "Book covers - pdf"(because of the .pdf extension) folder and has a subfolder called Abiotic Stress in Plants, which has the actual file inside.
Thank you in advance.

```
private function get_subdir($file_name) {



        return implode('/', array_reverse(explode('.', $file_name))).'/';
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it is a book cover?

Comment: hm...I was thinking that the .pdf extension will be associated with the Book Covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested.

```
<?php
$prepend = 'Book covers - ';

$file = explode('.', $file_name);

if(!is_dir($prepend.$file[1]))
    mkdir($prepend.$file[1]);

if(!is_dir($prepend.file[1].'/'.$file[0]))
    mkdir($prepend.file[1].'/'.$file[0]);

move_uploaded_file($file_name, $prepend.file[1].'/'.$file[0]);

?>
```

This should create the folders, if they don't exist and move your file to it. Needs a bit modification, but should work I think.

Comment: what if a user wanted to upload a .png (which has to be placed into a folder called png pictures)...etc...?  I need more of a general solution. What If your only input is $file_name...where you get the name of the file and extension...how would you handle this in order to get the result needed. It's just one method...

Comment: Check this out...this is the complete code...check out the link https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-Subfolder-example

Comment: How should PHP know, whether you want "book covers" for pdf?! You have to do that by your own. You gave us an example, I gave you some sample code. That's it...

Comment: What do you think of this?                                           return str_replace('/png/', '/Cover/', implode('/', array_reverse(explode('.', $file_name))).'/');